# How to display code block in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pre

I'm trying to create some website about AngularJS in AngularJS ;-) I've added `ng-app` on `body` element, and now all my code snippets (which are all in `<pre><code> ... </code></pre>` tags) are parsed by angular (it adds ng-binding class for example). Is there a way to tell angular that given block is only code snippet and should't be parsed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [ngNonBindable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) directive

For example:

```
<div ng-non-bindable>Ignored: {{1 + 2}}</div>
```